# Why is php str_pad only working every 3rd time for Unicode Character “─”

Tags: php, unicode

I am doing a simple **str_pad** with the Unicode Character “─” https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2500

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    echo str_pad("", $i,"─");
    echo "\n";
}
```

But the output in PHP CLI is displaying :

```
▒
▒
─
─▒
─▒
──
──▒
──▒
───
───▒
───▒
────
────▒
────▒
─────
─────▒
─────▒
──────
...
```

So it appears every 3rd line is correct, but the 1st and 2nd have a different end of line character.

But if I used **str_repeat** this works fine :

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    echo str_repeat("─", $i);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Results in :

```
─
──
───
────
─────
──────
───────
────────
─────────
──────────
...
```

So **str_repeat** works fine, but **str_pad** has a very weird and unexpected result. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try this echo echo str_repeat("─", $i)."<br>";

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a multibyte issue.

A quick way to get **str_pad** to work using Unicode characters

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    echo str_pad("", $i*strlen("─"),"─");
    echo "\n";
}
```

So this will give the desired output of :

```
─
──
───
────
─────
──────
───────
────────
...
```

But this will break when you actually have a string to pad out :

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    echo str_pad("X", $i*strlen("─"),"─");
    echo "\n";
}
```

Becomes :

```
X
X▒
X─▒
X──▒
X───▒
X────▒
X─────▒
....
```

So just need to use the multibyte version example :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php#116244

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    echo mb_str_pad("X", $i,"─");
    echo "\n";
}

function mb_str_pad($str, $pad_len, $pad_str = ' ', $dir = STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = NULL)
{
    $encoding = $encoding === NULL ? mb_internal_encoding() : $encoding;
    $padBefore = $dir === STR_PAD_BOTH || $dir === STR_PAD_LEFT;
    $padAfter = $dir === STR_PAD_BOTH || $dir === STR_PAD_RIGHT;
    $pad_len -= mb_strlen($str, $encoding);
    $targetLen = $padBefore && $padAfter ? $pad_len / 2 : $pad_len;
    $strToRepeatLen = mb_strlen($pad_str, $encoding);
    $repeatTimes = ceil($targetLen / $strToRepeatLen);
    $repeatedString = str_repeat($pad_str, max(0, $repeatTimes)); // safe if used with valid utf-8 strings
    $before = $padBefore ? mb_substr($repeatedString, 0, floor($targetLen), $encoding) : '';
    $after = $padAfter ? mb_substr($repeatedString, 0, ceil($targetLen), $encoding) : '';
    return $before . $str . $after;
}
```